# DEM data (Grid Text) to Raster Image using C++

Tags: c++, gis, geospatial, elevation

I want to convert such text format DEM data to Raster format using C++.
Please tell me if you have any ideas.
id, x, y, height

Comment: I would suggest you use [libgdal](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) for this.  Unfortunately you haven't really provided much of a code question for anyone to answer on StackOverflow.  Consider editing your question to add a code example of what you have been trying already and your exact issue if you'd like answers here, and if you just want recommendations for software / libraries for this or anything else in future, I'd suggest you ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you your answer.
I will use GDAL C++ API.